# add data to wtforms by reference

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to preload form data in wtforms with data from my database without knowing the column names.

this works so long as I know the column name I want.

```
form.column.data=User.query.get(1).first().column
```

what I want to do is go over all the columns like so:

```
for attr, value in User.query.get(1).__dict__.iteritems():
 form.attr.data = value
```

doing so gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'EditUsersForm' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to get to work specifically.

forms.py

```
class EditUsersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        exclude=['password_hash']
```

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    #mobilitys = db.relationship('Mobility', backref='username', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<user> %r' % (self.username)
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/manpower_edit_users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manpower_edit_users():
    form=QueryAllUsers(request.form)
    forms=EditUsersForm(request.form)
    '''
    if forms.validate():
        print("validate")
        print("forms.validate=",forms.validate)
        flash("User added")
    '''
    if request.method == "POST":
        for attr, value in User.query.get(user_list).__dict__.iteritems():
            forms.attr.data=value
    elif request.method == "GET":
        for attr, value in User.query.get(1).__dict__.iteritems():
            forms.attr.data=value
    return render_template('manpower_edit_users.html',title='Manpower Edit User', form=form, forms=forms)
```

Comment: Try `form[attr].data = value` instead of `form.attr.data = value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edit_user_form = EditUsersForm(obj = User.query.get(1))
```

You can populate a form from data. The keyword argument `obj` in documentation of `WTForms` said:

> obj – If formdata has no data for a field, the form will try to get it from the passed object.

Comment: From the review queue : Please add some explanation to your answer. Thanks.